# Issue compiling with AWS Codebuild (vue.js project)

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration

i'm trying to compile a vue.js project using AWS Codebuild, but it gets stuck in the build phase.
It gives me this error (running with sudo):

> [Container] 2021/11/26 18:06:02 Running command sudo npm install
> /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh:
> sudo: not found
>
> [Container] 2021/11/26 18:06:02 Command did not exit successfully sudo
> npm install exit status 127 [Container] 2021/11/26 18:06:02 Phase
> complete: BUILD State: FAILED [Container] 2021/11/26 18:06:02 Phase
> context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while
> executing command: sudo npm install. Reason: exit status 127

I don't know if i have configured in a wrong way the Codebuild settings.

And it gives me this error (without sudo):

```
[Container] 2021/11/29 15:06:08 Running command npm run build

> company@0.1.0 build /codebuild/output/src868393770/src
> vue-cli-service build

sh: 1: vue-cli-service: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! company@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the company@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-11-29T15_06_11_998Z-debug.log

[Container] 2021/11/29 15:06:12 Command did not exit successfully npm run build exit status 126
[Container] 2021/11/29 15:06:12 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/11/29 15:06:12 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm run build. Reason: exit status 126
```

Or if i'm using the wrong commands to compile it. **The buildspec.yml is this**:

```yml
version: 0.2

phases:
   build:
     commands:
       - echo Build Phase
       - sudo npm install
       - sudo npm run build
   post_build:
     commands:
       - echo PostBuild Phase
       - aws s3 sync ./dist $S3_BUCKET
```

Answer (score 0):

In case without sudo,
As shown in the error log, actually error log is

`/root/.npm/_logs/2021-11-29T15_06_11_998Z-debug.log`
(The file name will change every build.)

If you can access that, you may find an actual reason of error.

If you want to share that, before sharing log, make sure that the logs do not contain user names or other important information.

The cause of the error is not known with the current information.
However, I have seen a case where a similar error occurs, though not with CodeBuild.
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5210

If your source code contains `node_modules` directory, please do not include the `node_modules` folder. (This will be created by `npm install`)

---

The following is the answer when the first "sudo npm" error occurred:

may be you don't need sudo to use npm.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/using-npm-packages-in-codebuild.html#npm-packages-in-codebuild-login

how about like that.

```yml
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build Phase
      - npm install
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo PostBuild Phase
      - aws s3 sync ./dist $S3_BUCKET
```

Comment: I have tried using and not using sudo, without sudo it's the same errors...

Comment: Your error was `sudo: not found`. so If you remove sudo correctly, I think error will be changed. Please update your error log.

Comment: Thanks! Updated question with the logs

Comment: I have updated my answer, but it may not help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use sudo. But remember that CodeBuild needs permissions to run sync with your S3 bucket. The simplest way to compile it is:

```
    version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 16
    commands:
      - npm install

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - npm run lint

  build:
    commands:
      - npm run build

  post_build:
    commands:
      - aws s3 sync dist s3://yourbucketname/app-name
```