# Is there a way of logging more information on AWS CodeBuild?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm

so I have a deployed React web App on aws codepipeline, I just added new features to the project and pushed them to github, which trigger a build. I got an email a few seconds later saying that it had failed, I went there to check and came across an error which didn't make much sense.

Here is the log:

```
[Container] 2022/10/19 18:17:58 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2022/10/19 18:17:58 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
[Container] 2022/10/19 18:17:58 Running command npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src890598757/src/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src890598757/src/package.json'
npm WARN src No description
npm WARN src No repository field.
npm WARN src No README data
npm WARN src No license field.

up to date in 0.683s
found 0 vulnerabilities


[Container] 2022/10/19 18:18:11 Running command npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help init` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
package name: (src) 


[Container] 2022/10/19 18:18:12 Command did not exit successfully npm init exit status 1
[Container] 2022/10/19 18:18:12 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2022/10/19 18:18:12 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm init. Reason: exit status 1
```

** EDIT **
Here is my YAML file:

```
version: 1
applications:
  - frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - npm i
        build:
          commands:
            - npm run build
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: build
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
    appRoot: client
```

[image]

Now, I have checked and double-checked my repo and branch, and everything is exactly the same as before, I do have the package.json there and the package-lock.json, so this isn't making much sense.

I referred to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html to try and find a solution but came short-handed, and [Issue compiling with AWS Codebuild (vue.js project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70381022/issue-compiling-with-aws-codebuild-vue-js-project) which is another question that got a codebuild error, however, I couldn't reach any conclusions.

I'm sure this is a dumb mistake, so I'd like to know if there is any way where I could get more info on my logs and be able to solve this and further errors I'll be getting.

Answer (score 0):

Additional logging would be up to you, to add some extra logging level to the commands your CodeBuild script is running. CodeBuild can't magically make the `npm` command spit out extra logging, that would be up to you to add the flags or environment variables necessary to direct `npm` to spit out more logs.

In this instance I don't think additional logging is needed though. The error is obvious. You have added an `npm init` command to your CodeBuild script, and that command is sitting there waiting on user interaction to enter some values. You haven't configured your `npm` commands correctly to run in a non-interactive environment.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer. My question here is, before the npm init, when the codebuild runs the npm install, it isn't finding the package.json, which it was previously. Any thoughts on where I could start from here?

Comment: Btw I added my yaml file (without the npm init now), please lmk what you think

Comment: If it isn't finding the package.json file then you need to add some `ls -l` commands or something to debug the issue to make sure the commands aren't running in the wrong directory or something.